# 3D Text Rotation with the camera in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm a beginner with Unity3D and all related with game development. Recently, I'm trying to do a simple program in order to implement it in the HoloLens. The goal is to have a 3D Text ("_text") which moves in the direction where the camera moves, that is working really well. However, when I move my head (with the HoloLens) (+/-)90 degrees, I can't read the text because I'm not facing the text, with 180 degrees I see my 3d Text inverted. I would appreciate if anyone can help me. :)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TextManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject _text;
    public TextMesh _startText;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {  
        if (_text == null) _text = GameObject.Find("StartText");
        if (_startText == null) _startText = GameObject.Find("StartText").GetComponent<TextMesh>();   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (_text.activeSelf)
        {
            var camPos = Camera.main.transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward;
            _text.transform.position = camPos;
            _text.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * 0.025f;            
        }

        else
        {
            Debug.Log("deactive _startText");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a billboard behaviour (the text is always looking to the camera) you have to apply the changed camera rotation to the text mesh as well:

```
_text.transform.rotation = Camera.main.transform.rotation;
```

To get a more emerging 3D experience it sometimes can be useful to just flip the text by 180° when the camera goes behind, but leave the overall orientation. To achieve this:

```
        Vector3 objectNormal = _text.rotation * Vector3.forward;
        Vector3 cameraToText = _text.transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position;
        float f = Vector3.Dot (objectNormal, cameraToText);
        if (f < 0f) 
        {
            _text.Rotate (0f, 180f, 0f);
        }
```

Comment: I also found [this snippet](https://forum.unity.com/threads/make-3d-text-always-face-camera.73993/): `_text.transform.LookAt(Camera.main.transform);` which can be used instead of `_text.transform.rotation = Camera.main.transform.rotation;` it makes the surface of the text always look towards the player rather than rotating the text according to the player's rotation.

Comment: Never mind; that results in flipped text. Found a different approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59021768/991496) though: `_text.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation((_text.transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position).normalized);`.