# transform.LookAt on 3d text is showing the text backwards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2019.2.

Here is my code:

```
GameObject[] damageTexts = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("CombatText");

foreach (GameObject damageText in damageTexts)
{
    damageText.transform.LookAt(Camera.main.transform);
}
```

It is making all 3D Texts which I want to look at the camera. However the text is backwards written ?
Why? How can I fix that?

Comment: This is likely because 3D Text Mesh has the forward transform pointing in the reverse direction (why, who knows). Either put them inside a parent object with the correct orrientation, or LookAt a point behind the text relative to the camera (camera pos + (camera pos - text pos) * 2).

Answer (score 3):

`LookAt`

> Rotates the transform so the forward vector points at /target/'s current position.

Unity UI components usually have their forward vector pointing **away** from the camera. So you need to always invert the direction if you want to use `LookAt`

```
damageText.transform.LookAt(damageText.position - Camera.main.transform.position);
```

This simply makes it look at a position in the opposite direction.

---

You can also use `LookRotation`

```
damageText.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation((damageText.position - Camera.main.transform.position).normalized);
```